# how can i to get todays date in control textbox when program is launched C#

Tags: c#, date

it comes up when i hit the calculate button AND it returns the age, but not before.  i want it to be already there when i run the program.

also, how can i change the format to MM/DD/YY?
i tried changing my computer's date format, that wont work.

private void BCALCULAREDAD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
    {
        DateTime FECHANAC;
        DateTime FECHAACT;
        FECHANAC = Convert.ToDateTime(TFECHANAC.Text);
        FECHAACT = DateTime.Today;
        int EDAD = DateTime.Now.Year - FECHANAC.Year;
        TFECHAACT.Text = FECHAACT.ToString("d");
        TEDAD.Text = Convert.ToString(EDAD) + " AÑOS";
    }
```

Comment: You use far more uppercase letters than the rest of the C# devs in the world. Please review the C# naming conventions

Comment: You can just initialize the property just as you do above, except copy the code to the constructor. See duplicate.

Comment: @CaiusJard alright let me remove the upper cases to see if i can get the date on the textbox. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
        textBox1.Text = dateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yy");
    }
}
```

Simply subscribe to the form load event.

Comment: it will show the time also. But used needs only date.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    textBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yy");
 }
```